# jQuery chaining and toggle not running

Tags: jquery, toggle, chaining

If I run this code,

```
var waitRow = $(this).parent().parent().next().get(0);
$(waitRow).children('td:nth-child(2)').html('some text').toggle();
```

toggle is not called.

If I instead write the following code it works. Why?

```
var waitRow = $(this).parent().parent().next().get(0);
$(waitRow).children('td:nth-child(2)').html('some text');
$(waitRow).toggle();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are toggling the child element, not waitRow, I believe you could use `.end()` for this:

```
$(waitRow).children('td:nth-child(2)').html('some text').end().toggle();
```

To go back to the parent. Or use `.parent()` again.

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/end

Comment: It descends back to the prior jQuery object from the object it's currently at.

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to select an answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one tries to toggle the first item in the `children('td:nth-child(2)')` wrapped set. The html() method returns the first matched item and not the whole collection.

The second one toggles the whole row.